# Extracting a value for every year at the same date as today

Tags: vba, excel

I want to code something on VBA but I have no clue how to: 
I have data with one column for the date (everyday from 1998 to today) and one column for the prices.

What I want to do is for every year, on the same day as today, show what was the price, on a different excel sheet.

For example : if today is 28/08/2018, I want to know what was the price on 28/08/2017, 28/08/2016,..., 28/08/1998.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show them how?  A simple formula will do this.

Comment: I want to display the prices for every year, in a different Excel Sheet.

Comment: Does it have to be vba?

Comment: It's a small part of my VBA code. It will be linked to values from that code and it will be within an if function. 
So I think it has to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the values into an array and loop that array. Compare if the 5 left characters of column 1 (dates) match  the left 5 of today's date (returned with the Date function). Store qualifying values into a dictionary. Write the dictionary out to the a sheet at the end. You could also simply use:
`If Format$(arr(i, 1), "dd/mm") = Format$(Date, "dd/mm")` Then  if dates.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim arr(), i As Long, results As Object
    Set results = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arr = .Range("A2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value '< read columns A and B into an array (Dates and Prices)
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1) '< Loop the dates in the array (column 1)
            If Left$(arr(i, 1), 5) = Left$(Date, 5) Then 'compare whether left 5 characters match i.e. same dd/mm irrespective of year
              results(arr(i, 1)) = arr(i, 2)  'if match add the arr(i,1) date as key to dictionary; add the arr(i,2) price as the value associated with the key
            End If
        Next
    End With
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A1").Resize(results.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(results.keys)
        .Range("B1").Resize(results.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(results.items)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Here is an example of the comparison, if it were done in the sheet, showing a qualifying row. This comparison is done for every row which are stored in the array.

[image: test]

The dictionary, `results`, ends up having the qualifying row column A (`date`) as key, and column B (`Price`) as value.

You can access all the `.Items` or `.Keys` of the final dictionary producing an array in each case which can be tranposed to write to columns in the sheet.

Your dictionary will end up storing key value pairs of qualiying rows, a sample of which would look like:

[image: sheet]

Depending on formatting in sheet you might instead need:

```
If Format$(arr(i, 1), "dd/mm") = Format$(Date, "dd/mm") Then
```

---

Test run:

[image]

Comment: What part would you like explaining more? I have added more notes in with the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I have just seen the notes on the code. It makes more sense now. But still not working for me..

Comment: There is no error message, it runs fine. But no result on my sheet 2.

Comment: Yes I have the dates in column A and prices in B. And in Excel, I have converted the date format to be a date. Should I convert it as a date on VBA ?

Comment: Still nothing. Should it be within a command button sub to work?

Comment: Oh so it works when it's in a module like in your screenshots. But when it's in my userform, it doesn't work.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention an userform. Put a button on your userform and call this sub from that button click event. Hopefully that should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and your patience. It works!

Comment: yey! we got there :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal but tried and it works, as long as the date and the target day is set to text:

```
Public Sub Test()

Dim i As Integer

    i = 0

    For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5")

        If Left(c.Value, 6) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D1").Value Then

            i = i + 1 

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i & ":F" & i).Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value

        End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For a VBA answer I would suggest something like:

```
Public Function GetPriceOnEachYear(source As Range, prices As Range) As Object()

Dim rng As Range

Dim answer() As Object

last = 0

For Each rng In source

    If Month(rng.Value) = Month(Now) And Day(rng.Value) = Day(Now) Then
        rowdiff = rng.Row - source.Row
        columndiff = rng.Column - source.Column
        ReDim Preserve answer(0 To last)
        Set answer(last) = prices(rowdiff + 1, columndiff + 1)
        last = last + 1
    End If

Next rng

GetPriceOnEachYear = answer

End Function
```

I didn't do any type safety, and the answer is an array of ranges, if you would like only the value, then instead of `Set answer(last) = prices(rowdiff + 1, columndiff + 1)` you could use `answer(last) = prices(rowdiff + 1, columndiff + 1)`.

Comment: So here "source" and "prices" are the name of the variables as they are named on my Excel sheet? 
Sorry if the answer is too obvious, I'm completely new to VBA.

Comment: No, it is the name of a function.
If you have named ranges you can use on VBA
`x = GetPriceOnEachYear(Range("Date"),Range("Price"))`
And x will be an array with the ranges of each price on the same day.
You can also call this function on a cell `=GetPriceOnEachYear(A2:A30,B2:B30)` and CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER will give you the array function
I really recommend you use some basic tutorial if you couldn't use the function as it is.